# Type mismatch for typesafe vectors implementation

Tags: scala, type-level-computation

I am trying to implement typelevel vectors. It all worked well until I tried to implement the function `add`, which is meant to add two vectors (of same dimensions).

This is what I have so far:

```
object Vector {

  type Vector1[A] = Ex[A, Vector0[A]]

  def of[A](a1: A): Vector1[A] = Ex(Vector0[A](), a1)

  type Vector2[A] = Ex[A, Vector1[A]]

  def of[A](a1: A, a2: A): Vector2[A] = of(a1).ex(a2)

  type Vector3[A] = Ex[A, Vector2[A]]

  def of[A](a1: A, a2: A, a3: A): Vector3[A] = of(a1, a2).ex(a3)

}

trait Vector[A] {

  type Same[B] <: Vector[B]
  type Self <: Vector[A]

  def ex(a: A): Vector[A]

  def add(that: Self): Self

  def map[B](f: A => B): Same[B]

  def forEach(f: A => Unit): Unit
}

case class Vector0[A]() extends Vector[A] {

  type Same[B] = Vector0[B]
  type Self = Vector0[A]

  def ex(that: A): Ex[A, Self] = Ex[A, Self](this, that)

  def add(that: Self): Self = Vector0[A]()

  def map[B](f: A => B): Same[B] = Vector0[B]()

  def forEach(f: A => Unit): Unit = ()
}

case class Ex[A, V <: Vector[A]](v: V, a: A) extends Vector[A] {

  type Same[B] = Ex[B, V#Same[B]]
  type Self = Ex[A, V]

  def ex(that: A): Ex[A, Self] = Ex[A, Self](this, that)

  def add(that: Self)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): Self = Ex[A, V](v.add(that.v), num.plus(a, that.a))

  def map[B](f: A => B): Same[B] = Ex[B, V#Same[B]](v.map(f), f(a))

  def forEach(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
    v.forEach(f)
    f(a)
  }
}
```

This is more code than might be necessary for solving the problem, but it might be helpful for any discussion.

Now, take a look at `add` in `Ex` ("ex" stands for "extrude", e.g. adding one more dimension to a vector).

I get the following compile error:

```
[error]  found   : that.v.type (with underlying type V)
[error]  required: Ex.this.v.Self
[error]   def add(that: Self)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): Self = Ex[A, V](v.add(that.v), num.plus(a, that.a))
                                                                                    ^
```

This does not make sense to me, as both `v` and `that.v` are guaranteed to be of type `V`.

I am using `mill` with Scala `2.13.0-M5`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: the `add()` method in `case class Ex` doesn't override the inherited (and abstract) `add()` method from `trait Vector[]`. The implicit parameter gives it a different profile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type `Self` in `Vector` is abstract and is only defined for a non-abstract subclass of `Vector`. You can have values of type `Vector` but the compiler cannot know the type of `Self` for that value. Therefore you cannot call `add` on that value because it is impossible to check that the argument is the right type (because the type is unknown).

In your `Ex` class the value `v` is type `V <: Vector[A]` which means it could be `Vector[A]`. But `add` is not defined for `Vector[A]` because `Self` is not defined, so the compiler complains when you try to call `v.add`.

Here is a simplified example:

```
 trait A {
   type Self // Abstract type
   def add(a: Self, b: Self): Self
 }

 case class A1() extends A {
   type Self = Int // Concrete type
   def add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
 }

 case class A2() extends A {
   type Self = String // Concrete type
   def add(a: String, b: String) = a + b
 }

 val a1 = new A1
 val a2 = new A2

 a1.add(1, 1) // Argument type is Int

 a2.add("A", "B") // Argument type is String
```

This all works fine because the types are known. But now make a value of type `A` and call `add` on that:

```
 val a: A = a1
 a.add(1, 1) // fails to compile
 a.add("A", "B") // fails to compile
```

This does not compile, because you have lost the type information for `Self` because in `A` it is abstract.

Put simply, you can't call a method whose arguments are declared to be abstract types.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand the problem now. But do you know how I can solve it?